# Retrieve only the items that are of type Non-Stock Item in inventoryID field

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm working an Invoices and Memos and Invoices screens and I have to filter the items that are of type Non-Stock Item.

[image]

In both screens they use the same attribute for the inventoryID field.

[image]

I'm not sure if I have to customize the ARTranInventoryItem attribute to retrieve only the items that are of type Non-Stock Item.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will change the *Customize Attribute* dropdown to *Append to Original* then you can add a PXRestrictor.  If you want to always limit to Non-Stock items, then the PXRestrictor is simply:

```
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemType, Equal<INItemTypes.nonStockItem>>), "Non-Stock Only")]
```

You also could do this in a graph extension using Cache_Attached:

```
#region ARTran_InventoryID_CacheAttached
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemType, Equal<INItemTypes.nonStockItem>>), "Non-Stock Only")]
protected virtual void ARTran_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
#endregion
```

Comment: Perfect as always, that works, thanks for your help. @BrianStevens

Comment: This was one of those WOW moments when I learned that technique!  Glad it works for you.  You can stack multiple PXRestrictor attributes, but remember that each one will limit  the results independently.  I don't have the code sample at my fingertips, but I've done them before where I needed something of an "if this, then restrict this way - if that, then restrict that way".  PXRestrictor has saved me from some serious (and unnecessary) rewrites.  Search for PXRestrictor in the code repository for examples, and likely you will find an example to fit any need.

Comment: Apparently PXRestrictor PXRestrictor is amazing, I'll study more about that.